# Azure cloud app cycling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, deployment, cloud

There is something in my azure cloud app that is causing IIS to reboot. 
Briefly, I deploy to Azure, progress is going for a while, sites are deployed but the role could not start and ends up cycling...in the management portal it says that the role is unhealthy.

What I have done so far:

- Checked the azure diagnostics,(wad-control-table and such).
- Checked the IIS logs on the azure machine(remote desktop)

The only thing I find is this IIS warnings.

> The application '/' belonging to site '19291949' has an invalid
>   AppPoolId 'ddcc23fe-8eee-4412-a4dd-56b50e18d9f2' set.
>   Therefore, the application will be ignored.
>
> Site 19291949 was disabled because the root application defined for the site is 
>   invalid. See the previous event log message for information about why the 
>   root application is invalid.

Which explains why the server is starting and stopping all the time, but that is just a symptom of the app itself I assume.
I am able to access the site within the azure role itself...and sometimes it's available from my own desktop, but not rendered correctly.

There is obviously something wrong with my project. And from the threads I find at here a SO it looks like it could be more or less anything, from faulty references to connection strings pointing to a local db. But how would I know where to look? The azure diagnostics doesnt give me any details. The project runs just fine locally with the emulator.

[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038992/azure-cloud-service-definition-problems)
[Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958864/azure-cloud-deployment-log-monitoring)
[Thread 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909798/azure-cloud-deploy-keeps-recycling)

**And my question is: How do I find the specific root cause here?**
How should I structure my trial and error with this project?

Comment: As a quick thought, what happens if you host your site in local IIS? And also what happens when you run the site in your local Azure emulator?

Comment: It works both with azure emulator and as local web site. Not a warning. I am considering going from the cloud to just a regular azure web site. It's a shame because it worked like a charm a couple of weeks ago. So something has been added to my code that azure don't like.

Comment: Can you try to repro with brand new Azure Cloud Services, create with altogether different names and create them freshly and then publish your site. And see what it happens?

Comment: I tried that yesterday, it did not work.
I am finding something...it might have something to do with this line:
"Failed to connect to client DiagnosticsAgent.exe"

This is one of the errors I get in the logs.

Comment: Have you tried this solution - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/07/31/windows-azure-role-instances-status-showing-busy-unhealthy-due-to-reuse-of-process-id.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried everything I found...the only thing that managed to solve the issue was to add an installation of Mvc 3 as a startup task for the WebRole. Finally!

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh369932.aspx#StartupTask)

[Tech 2 on this site](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/asp-net-mvc-in-windows-azure)

Answer (score 0):

Start with the troubleshooting scenario walkthroughs at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx.  That series of posts should walk through how to debug and find root cause for almost all role recycling and unhealthy role types of issues.

Comment: Oh, that is one link I have not looked through yet. Thanks! I thought I had found every possible link on the subject.

Comment: Yeah, one step closer thanks to that site.
Found this with the debugger:
System.TypeLoadException: Unable to load the role entry point due to the following exceptions:
-- System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: But I don't know how to fix it, I have the bindings in place and "copy local" on the assembly. My app use version 4.

Comment: "Unable to load the role entry point due to the following exceptions".    That means you need the binding redirects in your WebRole1.dll.config (or whatever your role entry point DLL is).

Comment: So I have only one WebRole, and the webrole name in the service definition is for ex. OpWeb, you mean I should create a OpWeb.dll.config somewhere which contains the bindings that my app.config and web.config currently holds?

Comment: Did not work. Damn this is a pain. Not able to start intellitrace either.